# How to get a Flutter Stream from RealmResults?

Tags: flutter, realm, stream-builder, stream-provider

I have created as Realm object and got it connected to MongoDB Atlas.

In Flutter StreamBuilder widget the stream parameter takes RealmResults.changes as a stream and it works.

```
StreamBuilder<MyObject>(
        stream: RealmResults.changes, //works
        builder: (context, snapshot) => ()
),
```

But if StreamProvider is used, the create parameter which requires a stream does not accept RealmResults.changes as a stream.

```
StreamProvider<MyObject>(
        initialData: MyObject(),
        create: (context) => RealmResults.changes, //error
        child: Scaffold()
)
```

Here the error shown undelined in red is:
The return type 'Stream<RealmResultsChanges<MyObject>>' isn't a 'Stream<MyObject>?', as required by the closure's context.
I am confused, can anyone help me. Thanks